# Popups & colorbox issues in Chrome

Tags: modal-dialogs

Hoping for some guidance here. Sometime in the past few weeks, my inline modal popups stopped working in Chrome. I had Colorbox set up at the time, both hand coded inline links and views colorbox triggers. With views, the links now force a page refresh to the home page with the colorbox query appended:

- i.e. ?width=500&height=500&inline=true#content

With hard links, the page refreshed on the existing page, with the same query string added.

After some investigation, I discovered that ONE page on the site still works, but it's part of a series of panel variants on a page. I've been through the variants with a fine toothed comb, but they're configured identically, so there's no clear reason why this one page should work when the others don't. I've also tested Chrome on two other (both older) laptops, with the same results.

I installed the Popup module to see if I could by-pass the issue, but the results are exactly the same. The popups work on the one rogue page but not on any of the others. So the problem isn't colorbox, but something else. Again, this is ONLY in Chrome. Firefox and IE both work fine.

I've tried creating solo links on basic pages, I've systematically turned off all the other components on all of the test pages ... nothing. I tried removing all of my custom jquery and disabled my custom modules. No dice.

Can anyone suggest another approach, or other possible conflict areas I can test?

Edit to add:

Looks like the working page is processing the link class as "colorbox-inline init-colorbox-inline-processed cboxElement", while the non-functioning pages are only rendering "colorbox-inline". It's the same block on all pages, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't be processed evenly.

The base colorbox inline code I'm using is adapted from the following:

```
<p><a class="colorbox-inline" href="?width=500&amp;height=500&amp;inline=true#id-of-content">Link to click</a></p>

<div style="display: none;">
<div id="id-of-content">What ever content you want to display in a Colorbox.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you see any JS errors in Chrome's browser console?

Comment: Yes, there's:  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: Looks like it's attached to the github prefetch call in the colorbox js

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a conflict with the Superfish menu module. Leaving this here because several other people have reported similar issues and this might help.